# conditional formatting with ranges

Tags: conditional-formatting

[image]

The image above shows what i am working on. When Putting in a date in the M column, it will then put in the day of the week in the O column. What I want to do is write a conditional formatting code to change the color of the cell in the O column if the day of the week is not there in the F-L columns. For example: in the 2nd picture, Row 14 does not have Fri in the F-L columns. I would want it so because of that, O14 changes fill color.

hope that helps

thank you, W

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

[image]